# Chrome Extension: Capture URL of the newest tab opened

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

my purpose is to capture the URL of the newest tab opened using a content script. I want to capture the URL of the new tab only if it was opened from a webpage which matches the pattern specified in the manifest.

My first though was to use this code in **content_script.js**, so it would be executed every time current page matches the pattern:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
    /* tabs.onUpdated */
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){ 
        status = changeInfo.status;
    });
    while (status != 'complete'){
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){ 
            status = changeInfo.status;
        });
    }
    /* At this point, url tab is complete so I can capture it*/
});
```

The problem is **content_script.js** cannot access chrome.tabs object.
Then I though that code should be on **background.js**. However, **background.js** does not know when the current webpage matches the pattern.

Any idea of doing this?
Thank you!

Comment: you need tab permission also, otherwise "tab" object won't be complete (it will miss tab.url). Why not putting logic in BG script to check for match?

Answer (score 1):

You can capture and log `chrome.tabs` events in the background page and then provide the most recent log to content script via `onMessage`.

If you are only wanting tabs with a content script, then just `postMessage` from your content script during initialization and log that message in your background page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I tried to do is to detect when a new tab was opened using right-click.
So, from **content_script.js** I listen for `node.oncontextmenu()` events. There I called `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` to send the message to the **background.js** and then `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener()` to wait for the **background.js** warning of "new tab opened".

Meanwhile, **background.js**, which have started running since the extension was enabled, was listening for the **content_script.js** message by calling `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()`. Then it will listen for a new tab to open, and it will tell the **content_script.js** when that happens:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
 chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
 chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: 'whatever'}, 
 function(response) {});  
 }); 
 });
```

I did not post the actual code cause it's too messy, and you would get confused.